Why does 'get_the_ID' work outside of the loop?
on WordPress Developer Resources website's page related to get_the_ID() function it says:

Retrieves the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop

But I can use it outside of the loop and it works without using get_queried_object_id() which is apparently recommended in such a case.
Why is that?
(little code snippet to let you understand what I mean):
get_header();

echo get_the_ID(); // Shows the id of currently displayed page.

// Here comes the loop!
$some_query_args...
$some_query_loop {
    echo get_the_ID(); // Shows the id of queried page/post.
}

get_footer();


The get_the_ID() function uses the global $post variable, which outside of the loop is sometimes equal to get_queried_object_id(). Within the loop, the $post variable is set to the current post within the loop.
As to why get_queried_object_id() is recommended outside of the loop, is because it does not use the global $post variable, so is less likely to be corrupted by loops.

note that sometimes the queried object might not be a post, e.g. on an author archive or a term archive it might actually be a WP_Term or WP_User object instead of a WP_Post object. get_the_ID will always return a post ID if there is a "current post" though

That's amazing, gentlemen!. That basically answers my question.
